# Why is this for loop infinite?

Tags: c++

I am working on creating a sort of minesweeper program in c++, and after running some tests I found that, for some reason I cannot see, one of my for loops never ends. I have looked over the code for quite some time now, and cannot see the reason. thank you very much for helping me, I am somewhat new to c++ and am very perplexed.

Here is the code:

```
for (int r = 0; r <= 8; r++)
{
    for (int c = 0; c <= 8; c++)
    {
        int num = 0;
        if (realmap[r][c] != 10)
        {
            if (r - 1 != -1 && realmap[r - 1][c] == 10)
            {
                num++;
            }
            if (r - 1 != -1 && c + 1 != 9 && realmap[r - 1][c + 1] == 10)
            {
                num++;
            }
            if (c + 1 != 9 && realmap[r][c + 1] == 10)
            {
                num++;
            }
            if (r + 1 != 9 && c + 1 != 9 && realmap[r + 1][c = 1] == 10)
            {
                num++;
            }
            if (r + 1 != 9 && realmap[r + 1][c] == 10)
            {
                num++;
            }
            if (r + 1 != 9 && c - 1 != -1 && realmap[r + 1][c - 1] == 10)
            {
                num++;
            }
            if (c - 1 != -1 && realmap[r][c - 1] == 10)
            {
                num++;
            }
            if (r - 1 != -1 && c - 1 != -1 && realmap[r - 1][c] == 10)
            {
                num++;
            }
            realmap[r][c] = num;
            Sleep(5000);
            cout << "test3";
        }
    }
}
```

If you see the problem, thank you very much. I will include the rest of the if statements if nobody can find a problem.

Comment: have you tried using a debugger, like MVS?

Comment: Why do you have nested loops modifying r and c twice?

Comment: Bart seems to be on the right track. You reinitialize the variable 'r' and 'c' to zero, which will prevent the outer loops to ever finish.

Comment: This code is really poorly written.  Why are you reusing r and c in inner loops?

Comment: Those have different scopes that should not be a problem.

Comment: @Borgleader: Fixed indentation, and corrected the brackets.... I deserve a medal I think ^^

Comment: What are you compiling with? Those for loop statements have redeclarations, that should be illegal.

Comment: And in the skipped if statements, you're not manipulating any of the r or c values?

Comment: Make the world a better palce and use a function `bool is_outside_boundry(int r, int c)` to check the boundary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(r+1 != 9 && c+1 != 9 && realmap[r+1][c=1] ==10
```

I have no clue what any part of your code actually does or checks, but this will reset c to 1 every pass that the first two conditions are satisfied and thus cause an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so that you're function is going into infinite loop.

The reason is those loop iterators have different scopes and is perfectly valid in C++.

But your code has `sleep(5000)` which waits for **5000 seconds** everytime it encounters it.
Remove the `sleep` and try running the code.

Comment: Sleep is measure in milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like @Bart is on the right track here. You have nested loops that are modifying the same variables. This is generally a sign that something is wrong. Try renaming your inner-loop `r` and `c` variables.

Comment: The nested loops are modifying different variables with the same name. Well, they were, but now that the code has been modified yet again, the nested loops are gone.